# Wait for observable resolution

Tags: typescript, http, async-await, rxjs, event-loop

I've been working in a project for few months now. The scope of it was to work on synchronous environment, no need for http requests and other extern asynchronous access. Now I have to fetch data from http requests. I had many of the following snippet of code:

```js
get foo() { return this.value; }
```

Now, with the use of http, I need to fetch this value, and when I receive it just set the variable to the response.

```js
fetchValue() { this.http.get(addr).subscribe(resp => this.value = resp); }
get foo() {  this.fetchData(); return this.value; }
```

This obviously does not work, as `this.foo` will always return undefined because of the event loop only triggering after all of this logic, so only after the function resolution the value is set. I also cannot loop in a while, as this will cause a synchronous execution never allowing the execution of the http request.

**Is there a way to force stop in the synchronous loop and then start the asynchronous and wait for it to finish ?** Or at least wait one function in the event loop to finish

I cannot refactor the code, not only because it will cause a complete remaking of the code and the more than double of the time spent to make it, but will also break backwards compatibility which is imperative for this project. So I need foo to return the value after it is set; I cannot add subscriptions, or resolution to promises in any other part of the code to deal with this.

**If this is not possible, why is it ?** I need a clear explanation of the language paradigm that impedes the use of this logic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "stop" event loop as it is basically the main mechanism of javascript. Stopping event loop will actually mean stop execution of the app at all :)

In order to get better understanding of event loop I'd definitely recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) - it is probably the best explanation of this topic.

Now, let's fix your code.
It is possible to "wait" for asynchronous operation to complete using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and thanks to [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax it can be done in quite pretty way.

First of all, since you are using rxjs, you need to convert your http call into a promise. This can be done using the `.toPromise()` operator.

```
async fetchValue() {
  this.value = await this.http.get(addr).toPromise();
}
```

Note, that I put an `async` keyword before function name, this allow us to use `await` inside this function. Await expects promise to the right and will prevent code below it to run until promise gets resolved.

Your second function now also needs to have async/await:

```
async getFoo() { 
  await this.fetchData();
  return this.value;
}
```

Tbh, I am not sure why you need it at all, as the first function actually does the same job, but OK, I am just trying to show you the concept.

Now, whenever you call `instance.getFoo()` you need to remember that it is asynchronous so you should use `async/await` inside that function where you call `instance.getFoo()`, or use `.then` to get the value.

With async/await:

```
async function someMethod() {
  const foo = await instance.getFoo();
}
```

With `.then()`:

```
function someMethod() {
  instance.getFoo().then(foo => {
    // all the rest code here!
  })
}
```

Again, I'd recommend you to spend some time watching the video above and reading docs for promises and async/await.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, I cannot use this solution. The public API that declares foo is being used for many projects, and it's expected to be a synchronous function. If I make it an asynchronous function all users of the API would need to make their clients async, and this cannot happen. I need a way to wait for the http client to respond, and then allow the calls to the api to resolve. Or something like that.

Comment: @MuriloMaestro, if you watched the video you should understand that it is not possible to implement in that way. You can have a synchronous getter for `foo` property, but then it will return either a value if it was set previously or the `undefined`.